# swapping "endianness" of floats and doubles

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'd like to switch the "endianness" of float and double values, it works OK, by doing something like:

```
float const v{1.f};

swap(reinterpret_cast<::std::uint32_t const&>(v));
```

Does there exist a better way to do the swap, without a cast?

EDIT: `swap()` is a C++ wrapper for gcc's built-in functions, I did not include it here.

```
uint16_t __builtin_bswap16 (uint16_t x)
uint32_t __builtin_bswap32 (uint32_t x)
uint64_t __builtin_bswap64 (uint64_t x)
```

Swapping of endianess is needed for a some data formats, like CBOR.

Comment: That doesn't swap anything. In fact, I'm pretty sure that doesn't compile.

Comment: The IEEE doesn't cover endianness but you might, in practice, assume it works the same way as integer. So yes it's ugly but it works by casting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point

Comment: Assuming sizeof(float)==sizeof(uint32_t)

Comment: @Christophe static_assert can help with that.

Comment: Doesn't this violate type-aliasing rules?  GCC complains about this with `-Wall` is set, just as if you cast a `float*` to `uint32_t*` and accessed it.  IIRC, the only safe way to do this sort of manipulation is through the byte representation.  `memcpy()` the float into a uint32_t and swap that.  The `memcpy()` should get optimized out anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is good practice to try and avoid casts, it's uses like this that are the reason casts exist. An endian swap is a raw data operation so in order to do it you must strip away the typing information, I would say that if it is not endian correct to begin with, then it is not a float and should never have been typed that way while in the wrong endianess state.

Answer (score 1):

Simply swapping the byte order is sufficient. memcpy the float into a char val[4], create a dummy char rvrse[4], then set;
rvrse[3] = val[0];
rvrse[2] = val[1];
...
Then memcpy rvrse back into the original float. The best way is to write a function similar to ntohl but use templates to make it work for all types.

Comment: there's the small detail of `std::bit_cast` these days. No need for `memcpy` I'd say. Just `bit_cast` into an int, swap, and then `bit_cast` into float again.

Comment: Fine if you're using a compiler that supports C++20. Otherwise, your solution isn't much help.

Comment: well, sure, c++23 is around the corner.